# Memory allocating error with coxph model

Tags: r, regression

I'm working with cox models and as I am adding more variables, I am facing a memory issue. I tried to subset my dataframe by selecting columns which have variables of interest but even then I am facing this problem. How can I overcome that?

My data has around 451,557 observations with 270 variables. 70 Percent of variables are categorical (strings).

```
coxdf_2<- coxph(surv_df ~ NS_group + age_at_recruitment + Gender + Alcohol_drinking + 
                              Smoking + Diabetes + BMI +  +Hypertention, 
                method="breslow", data = DFMODEL)
```

> `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 16.1 Gb`

```
coxdf_3<- coxph(surv_df ~ NS_group + SOC+ towndep_I + Education+age_at_recruitment + 
                          Gender + Alcohol_drinking  + Smoking + Diabetes + BMI +  
                          +Hypertention,
                method="breslow", data = DFMODEL)
```

> `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 24.4 Gb`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a 64-bit version of R on Windows (I'm not sure about other operating systems), then you can allocate additional memory to R with `memory.limit` function.

```
memory.limit(size = 25000) ## limit is set based on Mb
```

32-bit version (depending on the system, whether it is 32-bit or 64-bit) is limited to 
2 to 4Gb.

You can further read about [memory limits in R](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Memory-limits.html).

All that said, I would take a step back beforehand to make sure I actually need to deal with all that data and would investigate other alternatives.